# How to group the data in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, knockout.js

[image]
    Hello, 
    I am using the knockout.js for displaying the data with asp.net website with web api,Every thing is working fine but facing the issue for grouping the data as shown in the image above.

```
My object structure is some what like
-------------------------------------

Message{UserName,Text,Time,Date}

sample data
-----------

MessageList:[
new Message("FO","Thanks, Sir. Have a pleasant stay.","05:12","26-01-2016"]),
new Message("Room6 (Gebi)","You have a nice tool here,"03:24", "26-01-2016"]),
new Message("FO","Please contact us" "09:24","25-01-2016"),
new Message("FO","Welcome to our Hotel" "03:24","25-01-2016")
]

HTML used is:  

 <div class="row spacer-top" data-bind="foreach: Message">
      <div class="col-sm-12 row spacer-top">
        <div class="col-sm-2">                       
          <span class="fontStyle4" data-bind="text:SenderName"></span>                        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">  
          <span class="fontStyle4" data-bind="text:Text"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span class="fontStyle4" data-bind="text:Time"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">                        
          <asp:ImageButton data-bind="attr: { 'id': CommunicationId }"  meta:resourcekey="imgbtnMessage1" CssClass="btn pull-right btn-default" />                       
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have checked the the link you have provided. so my issue is binding the date from the object as i don't have fixed date array. In the link you have provided choice array is fixed

Comment: You can build the array of dates.